# Landing page can have how many pieces of FINANCIAL information?

Tags: landing-page

While designing a **landing page** for a retail banking site that possibly has to display n pieces of data, I try to adopt the principle '**more is less**' and when it comes to user having to assimilate 'cognitive heavy' information I'm trying to restrict it further. 
Is there a set of rules that can help/guide the designer determine the ceiling limit? I'm also considering the '[progressive disclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure)' and not finding it good enough as the data has to be displayed upfront. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, is there a reason why you want it to be so heavy? What is the problem you want to solve? Or in other words...what is the goal of the user when he's visiting that landing page? (except looking smart :p)

Comment: What is the purpose of the site?  What is the information?  Who are the users?  This is going to be a waste of time without specifics.

Comment: It's for a retail banking site of multi geography bank apologies for not being clear

Comment: What does the data look like is it tables or graphs or statistics?

Comment: It's retail banking and therefore no graphs but tabular structure is followed. Potentially could fill up about thirty elements but I'm worried it will crash the cognitive limit of the user

Answer (score 1):

Less is more? :p don't think in a website as a service catalog or brochure.. Just add the information and links that users will need! 
I always try to find the most frequent tasks (analytics helps a lot!) and design accordingly. Of course, you have many customer types, and have to analyze that first.

For exAmple..Tasks Like... Opening an account, check fees, enter the home banking, find closest atm.. Contact a representative.. Get quotes.. That should be on the visible and main navigation area if you know

Lastly, check abanca website! I much like the way they conceived the site

Comment: Thank you. Business users have listed a possible catalog of about thirty items to be displayed and that includes various international accounts, respective balances, currency, cards and color coded overdue indicator and so on. All are relevant and not all are relevant

Comment: That is a very good beginning. Many guys would suggest using card sorting or similar techniques to narrow down and prioritize the list. Thinking in tasks and scenarios also works if you have some empahty.. I also work in financial products and sometimes i see it gets messy (specially when every stakeholder or area wants to win this menu battle...). However, showing evidence of user feedback helps a lot!! Send early mockups to customers and people around and see their reaction. Good luck!